# How do I scale a whole figure in pic?

Tags: groff, roff

Given a pic figure:

```
.PS
circle "Foo"
arrow
box "Bar"
arrow
box dashed "Foo" "Dashed"
.PE
```

Is it possible to scale the whole diagram element's widths and heights?

I have tried `scale = 2` without success.

Comment: Note, if you are looking for a simple gui that can output `pic` files, there is `xfig`. It can also export to Encapsulated PostScript.

Comment: I have used `xfig` in the past, but I did not recall it could output `pic` files. It is good to know. I am however trying to see if plain PIC commands can speed up drawing flow charts.

Comment: Another language for flowcharts is [graphviz](https://sketchviz.com/graphviz-examples). It looks harder than it is.

Comment: Looks interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling a pic-picture does not really work. The scale variable seems mainly used when drawables are specified with a size.

You could try setting a maximum height, like in

```
.PS 1.5
<your picture>
```

but that will result in large texts in the boxes.

Reducing the font size too gives a more acceptable picture:

```
.ps -5
.PS 1.5
circle "Foo"
arrow
box "Bar"
arrow
box dashed "Foo" "Dashed"
.PE
.ps +5
```

In the end, I resorted to drawing the pic-drawings separately and embedding them as eps. This has the advantage that you can not only scale them, but also use them in-line.

Comment: How do you generate the EPS from the pic code? I have seen that sometimes the EPS includes the image as raster instead of vector.

Comment: I use a self-written pre-processor (`in3xml`; if you're interested it's on github), but basically the commands are `pic $blk.pic | groff $blk.groff |eps2eps -B1 > $blk.eps`, so it won't be rasterized.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width and height of the whole picture by providing them as arguments to the `.PS` macro, in inches. Try

```
.PS 6
```

`scale` only affect items that have been given an explicit size, for example `circle radius 1`, and also works as a divisor, not a multiplier. Eg `scale=2.54` is suggested as a way to have numbers interpreted in centimetres, so `radius 1` is of 1cm instead of 1inch, i.e. a lot smaller.